# Is the word "which is" omitted before "less"?

Tags: meaning

In *The Matrix Reloaded* (2003), The Architect says to Neo:

> The Architect: The inevitability of its doom is apparent now...as a consequence of the imperfection
> inherent in every human. Thus, I redesigned it based on your history...to more accurately reflect
> the varying grotesqueries of your nature. However, I was again frustrated by failure.
> I have come to understand that the answer eluded me...because it required a lesser mind.
> Or perhaps, a **mind less bound** by the parameters of perfection.

Is the word "which is" omitted before "less"?

Comment: Yes, this is an example of "[whiz-deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=24650)", so you may want to look up that term and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not omitted as such, this is a standard, though rare and formal construction, which could be paraphrased as "a mind that is less bound".

This is a "postpostive participle clause":  You can also say, for example

> The experienced gained will be useful.
>
> I took the path less travelled.

These are standard, but rather formal.